# my laptop shutdown when ever I lunch a flutter app on an android emulator or genymotion, but not when I lunch an android app on the same emulator

Tags: flutter

$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 2.2.3 at /home/jrhp/snap/flutter/common/flutter
• Framework revision f4abaa0735 (3 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
• Engine revision 241c87ad80
• Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /home/jrhp/Android/Sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/113/android-studio/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
• Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/113/android-studio
• Flutter plugin version 58.0.1
• Dart plugin version 202.8531
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.0)
• VS Code at /usr/share/code
• Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!

Comment: Open task manager and observe memory and cpu usage. Usually cross platform app consume more memory.